# Options for Eurostar travel affected by strike?

Tags: uk, public-transport, tickets, event-based-effects, tfl

My parents are due to get the Eurostar on Friday August 28th and there will be tube strikes.

Their train is coming from Lowestoft to Liverpool Street and I allowed 2 hours for them to get the St Pancras, but now I am worried with the strikes that they will be delayed.

If they are delayed, is there an option for them to get another Eurostar train?

Comment: How much stuff do they have? You can walk it in well under an hour, even if they can't find a cab or bus to take. Eurostar checkin closes 30 minutes before departure, so that's still time to pause part-way for a cold drink!

Comment: Another option is to walk to Farringdon (20 mins) then take a Thameslink train to St Pancras. Or more expensively, walk across the square from Liverpool Street to Moregate, Great Northern service to Finsbury Park, Great Northern Service back to Kings Cross, then walk over the road to St Pancras

Comment: St Pancreas. Great!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the ticket you bought them. If you've been sensible, and bought them a [CIV ticket from your origin to London International](https://loco2.com/CIV-train-tickets) (more details from [the man in Seat 61](https://loco2.com/CIV-train-tickets)), then the CIV protections extend back to your original starting point. In that case, if anything delays you on your way to St Pancras, be that your train or the underground, then CIV protections kick in. No matter your ticket, Eurostar will (after verifying the problem) rebook you for free on the next train with seats that you can make. (Normal checkin times apply, as you exchange you ticket in the ticket office before security). If there's epic #fail, and you end up missing the last Eurostar of the night due to the delay, then they'll even sort out out a hotel for free.

If you were a bit of a muppet, and didn't buy a CIV ticket (they're normally cheaper! as they don't tend to have peak restrictions), then you fall back on Eurostar's generally great customer service. If you were delayed for a reason that's clearly not your fault, and if you've left yourself lots of time, they will normally (within some limits) take pity, and rebook you for free on the next available service with seats. If you're taking the piss, then they might stick to the rules, and ask you to pay a fare difference and change fee. Officially, they stick to the rules, but in practice if you've been delayed by an inbound train and left yourself lots of time before, they'll rebook you (and have me a few times)

However... You're probably fine. At a normal walking pace, it takes just under an hour to walk from Liverpool Street to Kings Cross / St Pancras. Eurostar checkin for most people closes 30 minutes before departure (10 mins for Carte Blanche and Business Premier customers). So, you've time to walk it, and stop for a refreshing cold drink part way.

Outside of peak times, you'll find a bus for at least some of the route, and [tube tickets + NR tube transfer tickets are valid on buses on reasonable routes during the strike](https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/tube/tube-strike). Taxis can be had if you want one, with a queue that'll be fairly long, but well under an hour.

Other options include walking to Farringdon (20-30 mins), then taking a Thameslink train to St Pancras low-level (5 mins walk to Eurostar checkin), or the slightly crazy and will-cost-extra option of a 5 minutes walk to Morgate, Great Northern to Finsbury Park, Great Northern back south to Kings Cross, then walk over the road to St Pancras (5 mins walk to Eurostar checkin)